# Cannot resolve resource item

Tags: .net, vb.net, resharper, resx, localizable.strings

I have a VB.NET project where I have a form (frmRun) and am using several resource files for different languages (i.e. English.resx, Portuguese.resx, etc.)  In my code I have included the namespace for System.Resources and defined a resource manager as follows:

```
Private rm As ResourceManager
```

On startup or when a user selects a language from a menu, I set the resource manager:

```
 rm = New ResourceManager("MyRootNamespace." & currentItem.Text, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
```

where currentItem.Text is "English.resx", etc. Since rm is defined at the class level I can now easily choose the string I want to show for the selected language as such:

```
btnStartStop.Text = rm.GetString("btnStartStop_Start")
```

This resource string "btnStartStop_Start" is defined in both English.resx (in English) and in Portuguese.resx (in Portuguese).

I'm using JetBrains Resharper and the issue is that the IDE is showing errors in the vertical scrollbar for every line where I use the rm.GetString saying it can't resolve them. If I click on the lightbulb in the left column of the IDE, it tells me I can fix this by adding this to resource item.  When I do, it's adding it to the forms resx file.  In this case this string goes into "frmRun.resx" and the error goes away.  But I'm not using frmRun.resx, I'm specifically telling it to use a different resx file (English.resx, etc.)  Interestingly even though these show as errors in the vertical scollbar of my IDE, they are not compile errors and the app compiles/runs okay.

How can I make it ignore looking for these resources in the forms resx file besides telling it to hide/not show these via the inspection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resource file should be the same name but with a language suffix.

For example

`WinFormStrings.de-DE.resx` for German

`WinFormStrings.fr-FR.resx` for French

The default will use the `WinFormStrings.resx` file.

Calls to `.GetString` will then pick out the correct file based on the current thread culture

A walkthrough that explains this can be found here: [Walkthrough: Localizing Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is something else you can do to make make the Errors go away. Go to Reshareper options and then to `Code Inspection` --> `Inspection Severity` under the language you are using you can find `Potential Code Quality Issues` here you can set the severity for `Cannot resolve resource` or `Cannot resolve resource item` if you dont want to search if for yourself you can also search the resharper options and type in `Resource` this will come up with what you are looking for.

We use our own ResourceManager implementation and we have the same issue, we set them to Hint / Suggestion so thew will be visible but not like errors.

[image]